# Drupal Change email address

Tags: drupal-7

I have a drupal site, and right now when a user Registers an email is sent to a particular email address to enable the user.

What I would like to do is to change that email address to another email address? How can this be done please? It must be done through php coding or from drupal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the following at: 
http://[yoursitename]/admin/config/people/accounts

Under "Who can register accounts?" : Visitors, but administrator approval is required.

When you set this option the admin should recieve an email when a visitor registers. The admin email account can be set at:
http://[yoursitename]/admin/config/system/site-information